# Wix Installer bundling Dotnet Framework 4.81 with previously built msi

Tags: .net, visual-studio, wix, windows-installer

I have attempted to build an installer which just bundles Dotnet Framework 4.81, and a simple test application.

I keep getting an error which says "wix.exe : error WIX0001: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.'

I created a Bundle (Wix v4) project below is the Bundle.wxs file.

```
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs" xmlns:bal="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/bal">
  <Bundle Name="TestBundleInstaller" Manufacturer="TODO Manufacturer" Version="1.0.0.0" UpgradeCode="d090a306-15fc-4e04-985e-83cbb3a2cf5f">
    <BootstrapperApplication>
      <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication LicenseUrl="https://www.example.com/license" Theme="hyperlinkLicense" />
    </BootstrapperApplication>

    <Chain>
        <!-- TODO: Define the list of chained packages. -->
        <ExePackage DetectCondition="WIX_IS_NETFRAMEWORK_48_OR_LATER_INSTALLED" InstallArguments="/q" UninstallArguments="/q">
            <Payload SourceFile="DirectoryTo\NDP481-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe"/>
        </ExePackage>
        <!-- <MsiPackage SourceFile="path\to\your.msi" /> -->
        <MsiPackage SourceFile="DirectoryTo\TestSetup.msi" />
    </Chain>

  </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

Below is the TestBundleInstaller.wixproj file.

```
<Project Sdk="WixToolset.Sdk/4.0.0">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Bundle</OutputType>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <OutputPath>bin\x64\Debug</OutputPath>
    <TreatWarningsAsErrors>false</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <None Include="NDP481-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="WixToolset.Bal.wixext" Version="4.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectReference Include="..\TestSetup\TestSetup.wixproj" />
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Read many Wix tutorials and documentation, and I still don't understand the error I experience. Any help greatly appreciated.

Build output:

Build started...

1>------ Skipped Build: Project: Test, Configuration: Debug x64 ------

1>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration

2>------ Skipped Build: Project: TestSetup, Configuration: Debug x64 ------

2>Project not selected to build for this solution configuration

3>------ Build started: Project: TestBundleInstaller, Configuration: Debug x64 ------

Restored C:\Users\JJacobs\source\repos\TestBundleInstaller\TestBundleInstaller.wixproj (in 2 ms).

3>wix.exe : error WIX0001: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.

3>Done building project "TestBundleInstaller.wixproj" -- FAILED.

========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 2 skipped ==========

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The root issue is that `ExePackage` needs a `SourceFile` attribute. In this case, move your Payload element to the ExePackage like so:

```xml
<ExePackage DetectCondition="WIX_IS_NETFRAMEWORK_48_OR_LATER_INSTALLED"
            InstallArguments="/q" UninstallArguments="/q"
            SourceFile="DirectoryTo\NDP481-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe" />
```

WiX v4 *should* have caught that as an error instead of crashing. The code in WiX for this case is complicated due to remote payloads.

I see an issue is already open, so it can get fixed in WiX.

Comment: I thought the Payload element was used to supply the source file location rather than the SourceFile attribute of the ExePackage element. Did the Payload element go away? Is it only used for remote payloads now? Did it behave like I tried to use it in a previous version?

Comment: The SourceFile attribute provides the executable to be executed in the chain. The Payload element is for any support files the executable needs. The use of the Payload element is not common and unnecessary in this case.

Comment: Tested the resulting executable. It installed my test application on my development machine. When I tested it on a virtual machine that did not have Dotnet framework 4.8.1 installed the test msi file worked but the Dotnet framework failed to install. The virtual machine is running a clean install of Windows 10 Business Edition.

Comment: You probably had NETFX 4.8 installed.

Comment: Whoops you're right. I found that release 528372 was installed which is 4.8. I really needed 4.8.1 installed since that is the framework my application targeted. Looking here: https://wixtoolset.org/docs/v3/customactions/wixnetfxextension/ I don't see a Wix property for checking 4.8.1.

Comment: That's a link to the v3 documentation (it says so in the big yellow box at the top). You want WiX v4 doc.

Comment: Got it thanks Rob. https://wixtoolset.org/docs/tools/wixext/dotnet/#net-framework-detection-properties-for-msi-packages. Don't know how I missed the big yellow box.

Comment: Changed this WIX_IS_NETFRAMEWORK_48_OR_LATER_INSTALLED to WIX_IS_NETFRAMEWORK_481_OR_LATER_INSTALLED. It works.

Comment: Rob I didn't realize you're the CEO of Fire Giant. You da man!!

Answer (score 1):

The `ArgumentNullException` is a bug in WiX. Please file an issue: https://wixtoolset.org/docs/gethelp/#bugs

Answer (score 0):

For completeness here is the new Bundle.wxs file.

```
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs" xmlns:bal="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/bal">

    <Bundle Name="TestBundleInstaller" Manufacturer="TODO Manufacturer" Version="1.0.0.0" UpgradeCode="d090a306-15fc-4e04-985e-83cbb3a2cf5f">
        <BootstrapperApplication>
            <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication LicenseUrl="https://www.example.com/license" Theme="hyperlinkLicense" />
        </BootstrapperApplication>
        
        <Chain>
            <!-- TODO: Define the list of chained packages. -->
            <ExePackage DetectCondition="WIX_IS_NETFRAMEWORK_481_OR_LATER_INSTALLED" InstallArguments="/norestart /q" UninstallArguments="/q"
                SourceFile="DirectoryTo\NDP481-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe">
                <!-- Payload SourceFile="DirectoryTo\NDP481-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe"/ -->
            </ExePackage>
            <!-- <MsiPackage SourceFile="path\to\your.msi" /> -->
            <MsiPackage SourceFile="DirectoryTo\TestSetup.msi"/>
        </Chain>

    </Bundle>
</Wix>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to use a registry search in a v4 bundle project.

```
<Wix xmlns="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs" xmlns:bal="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/bal" xmlns:bal.util="http://wixtoolset.org/schemas/v4/wxs/util">

    <Bundle Name="TestBundleInstaller" Manufacturer="TODO Manufacturer" Version="1.0.0.0" UpgradeCode="d090a306-15fc-4e04-985e-83cbb3a2cf5f">
        <BootstrapperApplication>
            <bal:WixStandardBootstrapperApplication LicenseUrl="https://www.example.com/license" Theme="hyperlinkLicense" />
        </BootstrapperApplication>
        <bal.util:RegistrySearch
            Id="SEARCH_DOTNET_RELEASE64"
            Variable="DotNetRelaseVariable64"
            Root="HKLM"
            Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full"
            Value="Release"
            Result="value"
            Bitness="always64" />
        <Chain>
            <ExePackage DetectCondition="DotNetRelaseVariable64 &gt;= 533320"
                SourceFile="DirectoryTo\NDP481-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe"
                InstallArguments="/norestart /q" UninstallArguments="/q">
            </ExePackage>
            <!-- TODO: Define the list of chained packages. -->
            <!-- ExePackage DetectCondition="WIX_IS_NETFRAMEWORK_481_OR_LATER_INSTALLED" InstallArguments="/norestart /q" UninstallArguments="/q"
                SourceFile="DirectoryTo\NDP481-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe" -->
                <!-- Payload SourceFile="DirecotryTo\NDP481-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe"/ -->
            <!-- /ExePackage -->
            <!-- <MsiPackage SourceFile="path\to\your.msi" /> -->
            <MsiPackage SourceFile="DirectoryTo\TestSetup.msi"/>
        </Chain>
    </Bundle>

</Wix>
```

Answer (score -2):

```
using Microsoft.Win32;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace TestCShorpInstaller
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Process installerProcess = new Process();
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();

            RegistryKey key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\NET Framework Setup\\NDP\\v4\\Full");
            if (key != null)
            {
                Object o = key.GetValue("Release");
                Int32 releaseVal = (Int32)o;
                if( releaseVal < 533320) {
                    processInfo.FileName = ".\\NDP481-x86-x64-AllOS-ENU.exe";
                    installerProcess.StartInfo = processInfo;   
                    installerProcess.Start();
                    installerProcess.WaitForExit();
                }

            }

            installerProcess = new Process();
            processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            processInfo.Arguments = @"/i TestSetup.msi";
            processInfo.FileName = "msiexec";
            installerProcess.StartInfo = processInfo;
            installerProcess.Start();
            installerProcess.WaitForExit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: C# code that does what I need. Targeted DotNet framework 4 in the hopes that it will be present on the PCs where apps will be installed.

Comment: Found that msiexec does not use relative paths so added the .msi and .cab files to my C# project then used the "Copy always" drop down in "Copy to Output Directory" build action. Also added the NDP48-x86-x64-Allos-ENU.exe file to the C# project using "Copy always" as well. For some reason the installer didn't run with the /q option. I am investigating.

Comment: This resulting executable installed on the Windows 10 Business Edition virtual machine very quickly and also installed the 4.8.1 Dotnet framework. Didn't need the /q option for msiexec.

Comment: Rob's comment about 4.8 having been already installed is correct. My test application targeted DOTNETFX 4.8.1. The C# code above checks for 4.8.1 explaining why I believed the C# code to be working, but not the Wix V4 bundle executable.